# Cannot attach the file .mdf as database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm new to MVC technology, going though a training material and struck up with below error message with Entity Framework.

Here I'm trying to get one record from SQL Server Compact database but error occurs in `EmployeeController` class at step:

```
Employee employee = empContext.Emp.Single(x => x.EmployeeID == id);
```

Error message:

> Cannot attach the file 'E:\DotNet\MVC4Application\MVC4Application\App_Data\MVC4Application.Models.EmployeeContext.mdf' as database 'MVC4Application.Models.EmployeeContext'.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot attach the file 'E:\DotNet\MVC4Application\MVC4Application\App_Data\MVC4Application.Models.EmployeeContext.mdf' as database 'MVC4Application.Models.EmployeeContext'.

Connection string:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="EmployeeContext" 
         connectionString="Data Source=E:\DotNet\MVC4Application\MVC4Application\App_Data\Database1.sdf;Persist Security Info=False"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Could someone help me with this error message, please?

Comment: Your connection string shows a `.sdf` file (SQL Server **Compact Edition**) being referenced - just a typo ?? So what do you **really** want - attach an `.mdf` (SQL Server - full version) or use SQL Server **CE** (with a `.sdf` file)??

Answer (score 3):

You can try the following (one by one):

- Deleting DB in SSMS
- Kill IIS
- Run the following commands via the package manager console:

  ```
  sqllocaldb.exe stop v11.0 (or 12.0?) 
  sqllocaldb.exe delete v11.0
  ```